# Warning:'RaisedButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use ElevatedButton instead

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have created this application named 'PIC FOLIO' some time back, this app provides images to the user just like image gallery website Pinterest. You may see the link of the code below as i have added a Hyperlink.
The code use to run perfectly but some days back i have reinstalled android studio and after i tried to run the application it is showing me a warning "RaisedButton is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use ElevatedButton instead."
What is the problem here? I have always used Raised button whenever i created an application with multiple screens, but this time around i have been issued warning?

[Link of the code](https://gist.github.com/ImVasav10/bdc8ad71e27ae40da7b0b03ba4826464)

Comment: What isn't understandable about the message?

Answer (score 6):

With **Flutter 2.0**, **RaisedButton** widget is **deprecated** and **replaced** by **ElevatedButton** widget. One example usage of **ElevatedButton** is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/67397877/15236786)

For more info, check official doc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html

Answer (score 4):

**RaisedButton is deprecated in the latest version of flutter .you can use the alternative of RaisedButton like this.**

```
   ElevatedButton(onPressed:(){},
                  child: Text('ElevatedButton'), ),
```

or you can use this button

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  MaterialButton(onPressed: (){},
                    child: Text('MaterialButton'),
```

Answer (score 1):

The RaisedButton of my code had color property, so ElevatedButton did not work. MaterialButton Worked for me, this allowed me to easily migrate my code to newer flutter version.

Comment: Migration. This was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you don't understand here. The error is "RaisedButton is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use ElevatedButton instead". Just do that.

Comment: I got the point but why Raised button is not working?

Comment: @krumpli ElevatedButton has less options. Life is not always as simple as you think.

Answer (score -2):

With Flutter 2.0 with null safty,
RaisedButton and other widgets in flutter has been deprecated and replaced
RaisedButton Replaced with elevatedButton, you can see all information here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html

about all buttons here : https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons